# Dynamic Justified Logo Text

Tags: html, css, text, format

I am trying to make a logo using css formatted text but I want the text to dynamically change and fit the DIV container (which is 1/3 of the page width) as it changes size and for the lines of text to expand to fill the width of the DIV right up to the left and right sides.

Currently I have the following HTML:

```
       <div id="logo_container">
       <span class="logo_name"> James Mitchell</span>
       <span class="logo_title"> Consultant ENT Surgeon</span>
       <span class="logo_website"> enthealth.co.uk</span>
       </div>
```

and CSS:

```
     #logo_container{
     float:left;
     height:10vw;
     width:calc(100% / 3);
     margin:0;
     }

     .logo_name{
     font-family: 'Catamaran', sans-serif;
     font-size:3vw;
     line-height:2vw;
     font-weight:100;
     color:white;
     }

     .logo_title{
     font-family: 'Catamaran', sans-serif;
     font-weight:100;
     font-size:1.69vw;
     line-height:0.5vw;
     color:white;
     }

     .logo_website{
     font-family: 'Catamaran', sans-serif;
     font-weight:500;
     line-height:1.5vw;
     font-size:2vw;
     color:white;
     letter-spacing: 0.3vw;
     }
```

Comment: `width:calc(100% / 3);` really?

Comment: the only way I know of getting the div to sit equally as 33.33% leaves a small gap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind changing you html, you can try this:

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
#logo_container > div:after {
/*this is what I have added*/
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
#logo_container {
  float: left;
  height: 10vw;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  margin: 0;
  text-align: justify; /* this line is new too*/
}
.logo_name {
  font-family: 'Catamaran', sans-serif;
  font-size: 3vw;
  line-height: 2vw;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: white;
}
.logo_title {
  font-family: 'Catamaran', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 1.69vw;
  line-height: 0.5vw;
  color: white;
}
.logo_website {
  font-family: 'Catamaran', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.5vw;
  font-size: 2vw;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 0.3vw;
}
#logo_container > div {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo_container">
  <div class="auto logo_name">J a m e s &nbsp; M i t c h e l l</div>
  <div class="auto logo_title">C o n s u l t a n t &nbsp; E N T &nbsp; S u r g e o n</div>
  <div class="auto logo_website">e n t h e a l t h . c o . u k</div>
</div>
```

Other wise you can just play with the `letter-spacing` property for each line

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help!  Please accept the answer by clicking on the tick below the voting buttons on the left.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I made a try, not sure wether it's what you want.
Only tested with Chrome.
Had to change span to divs...
Hope this helps : [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b2dbszej/3/)

```
<div id="logo_container">
       <div class="auto logo_name"> James Mitchell</div>
       <div class="auto logo_title"> Consultant ENT Surgeon</div>
       <div class="auto logo_website"> enthealth.co.uk</div>
</div>


body {
    background-color:black;
}

div.auto {
    height:33.33%;
    display:table-row;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}

#logo_container {
     float:left;
     height:10vw;
     width:calc(100% / 3);
     margin:0;
     border: 1px solid red;
    display:table;
}

.logo_name{
     font-family: 'Catamaran', sans-serif;
     font-size:4.5vw;
     font-weight:100;
     color:white;
}

.logo_title{
     font-family: 'Catamaran', sans-serif;
     font-weight:100;
     font-size:1.69vw;
     color:white;
}

.logo_website{
     font-family: 'Catamaran', sans-serif;
     font-weight:500;
     font-size:2vw;
     color:white;
     letter-spacing: 0.3vw;
}
```

Comment: not quite... I need the text to look like this:
http://www.elliottdevivo.co.uk/webdesign/logo.jpg